# Why is the colon missing after "http" in my URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Here is my reset password Haml file:

```
%p= link_to 'Changme', edit_password_url(@user, reset_password_token: @user.reset_password_token)
```

The first strange thing is that there is no route `edit_password_url`, but there is a route `edit_user_password_url`. If I take the second one, I'll end up with something like:

```
localhost:/users/password/edit.9?reset_password_token=yeePkkvDzaDj3DFFuXBq
```

Notice there is `.9` in the URL.

I changed it to be `edit_password_url`, but when I tested it on my production system, and received the activation URL email, the link turned out to be without the colon after `http`.

```
http//mywebsite.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=yeePkkvDzaDj3DFFuXBq
```

If the first strange thing is pretty acceptable, then the second one really should be fixed, but it seems there is no error in my code.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: In `config/environments/production.rb` try `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'www.mywebsite.com' }`. Also, run `rake routes` and make sure that `edit_user_password_url` is supposed to take a user ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely your edit_user_password_url is not supposed to receive a user id. Are you using Devise? I presume your code will work if you do:

```
%p= link_to 'Changme', 
             edit_password_url(reset_password_token: @user.reset_password_token)
```

To confirm, run `rake routes |grep password` and post the output